# ROW_NUMBER over PARTITION BY restart row counter between breaks

Tags: oracle, sequence, partition, row-number

I have a list of activities that is currently ordered by user, date and time of activity, and ID. I want to generate numbers for each group set by those same fields. Using the following code, I achieve considerable accuracy. However, there's a problem when the same ID is repeated at a later time and I need the row number count to restart instead of continuing from the previous iteration.

Here's my code:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USER_ID, foc_id ORDER BY USER_ID,  to_char(activity_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), foc_id) seq_nbr`

In the image below, we see that FOC_ID "A240" had activity around 2:20PM. Then FOC_ID "B410" had activity around 3:19PM, lastly the user returned to "A240" for additional activity around 3:20. Because there was activity between the first and second sequence of events of "A240," I need the row number (seq_nbr) to restart instead of continuing from the previous activity.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       activity_date,
       foc_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, mno ORDER BY activity_date ) AS seq_num
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY user_id
  ORDER     BY activity_date
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS mno
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( same_foc_id* last_row  )
  DEFINE
    same_foc_id AS FIRST( foc_id ) = NEXT( foc_id )
)
```

or, multiple `ROW_NUMBER`s:

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       activity_date,
       foc_id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, foc_id, grp ORDER BY activity_date ) AS seq_num
FROM   (
  SELECT user_id,
         activity_date,
         foc_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY activity_date )
           - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, foc_id ORDER BY activity_date ) AS grp
  FROM   table_name
)
ORDER BY user_id, activity_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( user_id, activity_date, foc_id ) AS
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '14:20:34' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '14:21:23' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '14:21:23' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '14:21:23' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:19:39' HOUR TO SECOND, 'B410' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:19:44' HOUR TO SECOND, 'B410' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:19:58' HOUR TO SECOND, 'B410' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:20:11' HOUR TO SECOND, 'B410' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:22:16' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'UVAC3', DATE '2020-11-04' + INTERVAL '15:22:33' HOUR TO SECOND, 'A240' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> ```
> USER_ID | ACTIVITY_DATE       | FOC_ID | SEQ_NUM
> :------ | :------------------ | :----- | ------:
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 14:20:34 | A240   |       1
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 14:21:23 | A240   |       2
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 14:21:23 | A240   |       3
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 14:21:23 | A240   |       4
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:19:39 | B410   |       1
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:19:44 | B410   |       2
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:19:58 | B410   |       3
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:20:11 | B410   |       4
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:22:16 | A240   |       1
> UVAC3   | 2020-11-04 15:22:33 | A240   |       2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97af6b40b0085318c1e36266cec5c573)*